# Is it possible to change admin Actions URL (not only the URI)

Tags: craft3, admin, craft-features, craft-pro

When Craft is in `headlessMode` my URLS for admin actions (ex. `/admin/set-password`) are set to the frontend URL (`SITE_URL`) instead of the Admin URL (`SITE_ADMIN_URL`).

Is this behavior as expected?

As my Frontend is using angular I would need to add a redirect on the NGINX server to get the links to work which is kind of a strange workaround. Shouldn't the Action urls use the Admin URL by default instead?

Current behavior:

`www.example.com/admin/set-password`

Expected behavior:

`cms.example.com/admin/set-password`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, just received the answer from the support. will add it here for anyone who has the same issue:

setting the `baseCpUrl` in the `config/general.php` does the trick:

`'baseCpUrl' => 'https://cms.example.com/',`